# DynamoDB - Querying for a NULL key in index

Tags: null, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with an index made up of the following keys:

```
Partition Key: channel
Sort Key: username
```

In my app, I need to pull records where the username is not set. I'm curious if this is possible (without a filter) and what the syntax should look like. I'm using the Go SDK, but that may not be relevant. Here's an example of the param structure:

```
{
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        :v_channel: {
            S: "redirects"
        },
        :v_username: {
            NULL: true
        }
    },
    IndexName: "channel-username-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "channel = :v_channel AND username = :v_username",
    TableName: "messages"
}
```

This, of course, fails. The error:

> query Error: ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type

I haven't been able to find an example of the proper syntax, and one posting I found stated that this may not be possible at all. The alternative is to pull everything and filter (maybe in DynamoDB, but definitely in code).

BTW, this does work:

```
{
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        :v_channel: {
            S: "redirects"
        }
    },
    FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(username)",
    KeyConditionExpression: "channel = :v_channel",
    TableName: "feedback-messages"
}
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: You can't. The sort key must have a value.

Comment: Confirmed - any query requires values for the keys in the selected index. Scans don't need both keys. But the only way to check for the absence of something is a filter. Thanks for your help.